# stepwizard stepPosition is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I integrated bootstrap step wizard for my application installer and i want to change button text based on the `stepPosition` and here `stepPosition` 'first' , 'final'  are working how can I get middle `stepPositions` of the `stepwizard`.

Can any one help me out?

```
if (stepPosition === 'first' || stepPosition === '3') {
    $("#next-btn")[0].innerHTML = "Next";
}
if (stepPosition === '4') {
    $("#next-btn")[0].innerHTML = "Install";
}
if (stepPosition === '5') {
    $("#next-btn")[0].innerHTML = "Login";
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `stepPosition`.?

Comment: I have a `'first'`, `'3'`, `'4'` and `'5'`, Where is `'2'` and `'final'`? We also need more context to it: how is `stepPosition` set? When does it change its value, ect... Please update your code with relevant snippets so that the behavior can be reproduced.